# ASP.NET, MVC - why ActionResult method asking for default control parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I have follow problem

I have a view ActionResults methods:
Both located in one controller - `TestController`

```
public override ActionResult Index(int pageNumber, int pageSize, string nothing)
{
    ...
}

public ActionResult getAJAX()
{
    ...
}
```

my global.asax file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "getAJAX", 
    "{controller}/getAJAX", 
    new { action = "getAJAX" } 
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Test", 
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Test", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, pageNumber = 1, pageSize = 50 } 
);
```

If I open `site.com/TestController/getAJAX` - I get the following error

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'pageNumber' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32, Int32, System.String)'

If open `site.com/TestController/getAJAX/1` - everything is OK

Why is `getAJAX` asking for parameters which are in other method?

Comment: What happens if you go to `~/Test/getAJAX`?

Comment: You first route definition expects the first segment to be the controller name so to call it you would need `.../Test/getAjax` (I assume what your really want is `url: "/getAJAX", defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "getAJAX" }`

Comment: Why is your `Index` method virtual? Controllers shouldn't inherit from each other (unless they're specifically designed as "base" controllers.

Comment: And the 2nd one should be `controller = "Test"` (not `"controller = "TestController""`)

Comment: I did mistake in startPost, post is updated

Comment: Unless your controller is named `TestControllerController` then your code is still incorrect!

Comment: yes, it was again mistake ) But problem still as above - if open site.com/test/getAJAX - appear error that not enough parameters, if open site.com/test/getAJAX/1 - everything is OK

Answer (score 0):

If your controller is called `TestController`, then everywhere in your URLs you need to use `Test` (i.e. `Controller` should be removed from the URL), for example, use `site.com/Test/getAJAX` instead of `site.com/TestController/getAJAX`.

When you try to navigate to `site.com/TestController/getAJAX` MVC is looking for a class called `TestControllerController`, and since it is not there then second route is used instead of the first one.

Additionally, you don't need `Controller` in your default route object, so instead of

```
new { controller = "TestController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, pageNumber = 1, pageSize = 50 }
```

you should be using

```
new { controller = "Test", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, pageNumber = 1, pageSize = 50 }
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Yes, absolutely correct, this again was mistake in code. But problem still available - if open site.com/test/getAJAX - appear error that not enough parameters, if open site.com/test/getAJAX/1 - everything is OK. Why it can be? ActionResult of getAJAX does not required any additional parameters

Answer (score 0):

As you see line `System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32, Int32, System.String)` in error message.

It is pointing to `Index(...)` action instead of `getAJAX()` action.

As per MapRoute in `global.asax` file, `getAJAX` will work for `"site.com/Test/getAjax"`

And `"site.com/getAJAX"` has matched  with `"TestController"` route as default route.

Solution:
Change MapRoute for `getAJAX` as

```
 routes.MapRoute(
    "getAJAX", 
    "getAJAX", 
    new { controller="Test", action = "getAJAX" } 
);
```